# How to fill ellipses in "provenance" library

Tags: r

I'm plotting a ternary diagram using [CRAN R](https://cran.r-project.org/) and a library called [*provenance*](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucfbpve/provenance/). I can draw some "confidence ellipses" by calling `ternary.ellipse(...)`. This function automatically draw the ellipses and return a 5 double list, so I don't know how to manipulate the ellipse and (particularly) I don't know how to fill it with color.

I've tried to use `col="Red"` or `fill=TRUE` as parameters, but it doesn't work.

Here's my simplified code:

```
library(provenance)

#File 
A <- choose.files(multi = FALSE, filters = cbind("Files csv (*.csv)", "*.csv"))

#Read the file
MP <- read.counts(A)

#Plot
T1 <- ternary(MP)
plot(T1,labels=NULL)

#Draw the ellipse
ternary.ellipse(T1, alpha=0.05, population=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=3) #how to fill this ellipse?
```

Just for example, you can use [this cvs file](http://ucl.ac.uk/~ucfbpve/software/PT.csv).

This is the result I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: I have never used that R package but I think you can't simply pass `fill = TRUE` or anything like that because if you look at the code behind `ternary.ellipse`  (i.e. `getAnywhere("ternary.ellipse.counts")` since `T1` is an object of class `count`) you will see that at the end it calls `graphics::lines(...)`. Maybe you can have a look at [ggtern](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtern/index.html)

Comment: Thanks @agila , `ggtern` seems to be the best solution!